# What is the closed form of $\int e^{x^2} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus

How can I do a closed form expansion of $\int e^{x^2} \, dx$? Please be specific as to which method I must use.

Comment: The [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) is defined as $$\text{erfi}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt$$Then you can use the Taylor series or Burmann Series expansion.

Comment: It's not an elementary function - it cannot be expressed using rational functions, radicals, exponential/logarithmic or trigonometric functions or any composition thereof. So we simply gave it a name.

Comment: This was proven by Liouville..............

Answer (score 1):

$\mbox{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2} \ dt$ is known (at least after multiplication by a constant) as the [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). There is no simple closed form for the Error function in terms of elementary functions such as polynomial, exponential or trigonometric functions.

Through a little manipulation, you can show that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^x e^{t^2} \ dt = i\mbox{ erf}(ix)$, which is known as the imaginary Error function. Clearly, since it's just a transformation of the normal Error function, it has no nice closed form either.

Comment: Not just "no **simple** closed form".  It is provably not an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

Comment: See "Elementary function" on wikipedia.