# Computing $\int\limits_0^x e^{t^2} dt$

Tags: integration

How can I calculate this integral: $\int\limits_0^x e^{t^2} dt$  ?

Will the usual Newton-Leibniz formula apply?

Comment: I can't remember being able to analytically compute this anti-derivative.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555588/what-is-the-closed-form-of-int-ex2-dx and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2159110/antiderivative-of-ex2-correct-or-fallacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{π}}{2}$erfi$(x)$

This is known as the imaginary error function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it will apply, but this function doesn't have an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions. Take a look at error function and it's definition.

Comment: More specifically, the [*imaginary* error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function).

Answer (score 0):

The anti derivative is erfi() function . Please check the link:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html

Comment: Perhaps it is better to say that the antiderivative **contains** the $\operatorname*{erfi}(\cdot )$ function rather than saying that it **is** the $\operatorname*{erfi}(\cdot )$ function.